Fourier series - finding its period from frequency representations
I’ve been given the following signal:
$$X^F(\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 2\pi a[n] \delta(\omega - \omega_0 n)$$
and I was asked to:

find it’s period
given $|X^F(\omega)| \ne 0$  only at $|\omega| = 0,3,6,8,9$ find the period of the signal now.
$H^F(\omega) \triangleq \sqrt{|\omega|} - \sqrt{\alpha}$ for a real and constant $\alpha$, find the alpha that gives the signal with the smallest period for $x(t) * h(t)$.

my attempt
I’m really trying but I can’t figure out the second and third points, my attempt though did lead me to believe I can represent the signal in the time domain as a fourier series:
$$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a[n] e^{-j \omega_0 n t}$$

I know that my signal is composed of different exponents at frequencies $w_o n $ - so the smallest frequency is $\omega_0$, and by the time it finishes a cycle every other frequency will too - it’s associated period time $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$.
I based on the previous logic  the solution should be unaltered even though some frequencies zeroed out, but that’s not the case. - why is that?
I’m a little clueless - the solution has a computation I don’t understand for $\alpha = \sqrt{8}$. here it is:

I’ve a test soon, so any help is enormously appreciated!


Hint for #2: n still runs in increments of 1. What does $\omega_0$ need to be to satisfy the $0,3,6,9$ conditions ?

If it's possible to think of the DC signal as completing a period at 0 time, the longest period I have is at $\omega  = 3 \omega_0$, so that's my fundemental (or longest or base) frequency and my period should theoretically be $\frac{2\pi}{T}$ - but 8 is there as well so they're not all divisible by 3 - wouldn't the fundamental frequency still be omega 0?

Edit: $\frac{2\pi}{3T}$

I think that since we’re looking for $\omega_0$ for which $2\pi\sum_n \delta(w -w_0n)$ isn’t 0 at frequencies $|\omega| = 0,3,6,8,9$ we want the delta to have argument 0 at these frequencies. Since $\omega_0$ is our fundamental frequency still we can look at a specific n, for instance $n=3$.
let’s demand:
$$\omega - \omega_0 \cdot n =0 \bigg|_{n=3, \omega = 3} \implies \omega_0= 1$$
from here we can ascertain T easily.
as for the next question, the filter is equivalent to multiplying omega by a factor, if we can zero out 8 we can tell that the gcd - fundamental frequency can be $3\omega_0$ - which gives us a smaller period :)

HINTS:

Note that the given numbers are not indices but actual angular frequencies. So your result should be a number, not just a multiple of the unknown quantity $\omega_0$.

In point 2, there's one number that doesn't really match the pattern of the others. If the filter eliminates that frequency (i.e., its frequency response is zero at that frequency), the pattern of the other frequencies will result in the smallest period.


